# i phone 5 screen replacement

Tags: iphone, hardware, hardware-recommendation, repair

Is there a difference between these two replacement parts ?

[60 Dollars](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DV6BN10)

[55 Dollars](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KJL0A5U)

[30 Dollars](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B3O38GK)

or is there another one you would recommend ? I am starting to repair IPhones and would like some advice thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There should not be much difference based on the type of products they are.
However quality wise you must do research ex: Reading reviews, googling the product, etc.
I don't really have any recommendation but you can try the research it should help.

Sometimes you gotta go with your gut, and you might also want to check out the return policy with Amazon because you may be able to order it and try it out and return if you don't like it or it's bad quality etc.

Comment: Yeah that sounds great but its not very helpful the actual reviews seem to be all over the place

Answer (score 1):

This is based purely off of my personal experience, so don't treat it like the gospel, grain of salt, all that jazz.

My Uncle recently repaired his iPhone screen with one of those $30 el-cheapo replacement screen assemblies only to have it fail days later.

Based on this personal experience of mine, I'd say Tre Scaggs' answer is correct in that you have to read the reviews and shop smart.